# Create mysql table in phpmyadmin sql window

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a `mysql` table in `XAMPP` sql command window within an existing `database` with following code

```
CREATE TABLE hello_world (
    id text NOT NULL,
    password text,
    contact text,
    email text,
    friends text,
    time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY id
);
```

but get the following error in `phpmyadmin`

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 9

Comment: text to be unique? :O

Comment: "time" is reserved word for MySQL, so you have to wrap it with backticks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to note here:

First, your syntax for the unique key is wrong, the line should read

```
UNIQUE KEY (`id`)
```

Second, a unique key has to have a fixed length in mysql, so you need to specify `id` like this

```
id varchar(10) NOT NULL,
```

**However**, you should be aware that using text as an id is usually not a good option. Consider using an integer and making it a `PRIMARY KEY` instead like in this example:

```
CREATE TABLE hello_world (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    password text,
    contact text,
    email text,
    friends text,
    time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Here is an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebe53b/1/0).

Comment: 3th thing is that "time" is reserved word in MySQL as it is data type

Comment: @bksi that is true, and it is not good style. However, MySQL is smart enought to tell it's a column name in this case. See the fiddle.

Comment: first of all, i need a table where i don't want extra integer `id` because i used `name` as `id` that can't be integer but `text` or `varchar`. I used first half of code.Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you know what you're doing regarding the fact that you have a text id, for instance...

In order for your specific query to work you need to change it to

```
CREATE TABLE hello_world (
id text NOT NULL,
        password text,
        contact text,
        email text,
        friends text,
time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY (id (/*#size of the index#*/))
);
```

this should run and create your table.

Comment: It will not.. I tried it ;)... still the fact that OP puts all fields of type text makes no sense.. but the name of the table is 'hello world' so he's probably just getting started by messing around a little bit ;)...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
CREATE TABLE hello_world (
    id int NOT NULL,
    password text,
    contact text,
    email text,
    friends text,
    time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You should define the id as primary key. If you need a field for text make a new field. But its much better to have a primary key. That key is automaticly an index.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this, you don't need to set text dataType to every field, Use appropriate dataType according to your application requirement for better performance :

```
CREATE TABLE hello_world (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255),
`contact` text,
`email` varchar(100),
`friends` text,
`_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
UNIQUE KEY `id`(`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with int instead of integer as that isn't support in phpmyadmin usually.

```
CREATE TABLE hello_world (
    id int NOT NULL,
    password text,
    contact text,
    email text,
    friends text,
    time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY id
);
```